# Hadoop JMX server Display Wrong File descriptor

Tags: 16.04, server

I use Ubuntu 16.04 server. I've set max file discriptor to `128000` and the following command get `128000` as output:

```
ulimit -n
ulimit -Sn
ulimit -Hn
```

But in the Hadoop JMX server the OS property `"MaxFileDescriptorCount"`
is displaying `4096`!

Here are some configurations:

- `/etc/security/limits.conf`

  star    soft    nofile  128000

  star    hard    nofile  128000

  start    soft    nproc   128000

  star    hard    nproc   128000
- `/proc/sys/fs/file-max`

  ```
  97255
  ```

In the case of file `/proc/sys/fs/file-max` I tried to modify it but I think some other processes overwrite the value.

In addition, I add the line `session required pam_limits.so`
to both files:

```
/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive
/etc/pam.d/common-session
```

Comment: Is the service started via `systemd`?

Comment: Yes, I created a Hadoop service that is started at the boot time.

Comment: In case it is `systemd` add `LimitNOFILE=128000` to the `[Service]` section of your *.service* file. Then `systemctl daemon-reload` to pick up the changes and validate with `systemctl --no-pager show <service> | grep LimitNOFILE`

Comment: Thnx! Can I run service in normal form, as when I run it using command line manually?